# Confidence Level for mean comparison among control and treatment group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, stata

I collected data where two players interacted with two choices each, where a 2x2 table resulted when representing the game in strategic form. The 4 outcomes are (A, A) ; (A, B) ; (B, A) ; (B, B). My null hypothesis is that the outcome (B, B) is more likely in the treatment group (Treat==1) than in the control group (Treat==0). The control group has 14 subjects and the treatment 16. How could I test my null? I could perform the test both manually or on STATA.

Comment: Try to look up chi-squared test, fishers exact test, simple logistic regression (with treatment as outcome variable and group as dependent variable), or comparing proportions of (B,B) in the two groups. Each one of them can easily be done in STATA.

Comment: Thank you so much! The Fischer Test works perfectly

Comment: So I get the Fischer's exact being 1.00 and the left-sided equalling 0.594. What conclusion can I draw apart from the independence of the two variables?

Comment: is 1 referring to you p-value? if so, there is no difference. What is 0.594 referring to? based on how you write it it seems to be a confidence interval lower bound, however with fishers exact test you should not get a confidence interval since it is a non-parametric method. Please explain you output in more details.

Comment: yes it is the p-value.